# Unable to connect to mysql jdbc database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am frustrated seeing this error and not knowing the solution. I am trying to connect to a mysql db with a server url but it is giving my mysqlException(stacktrace below). The code works fine till here:

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://server_url/db_name";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
String user = "user";
String password = "password";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,user,password);
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '172.23.251.154' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1070)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
```

Is this because I'm using a different version of mysql-connector jar? 
Please help me.

Comment: Looks like a GRANT issue to me. Try: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html

Answer (score 1):

From [Chapter 6. SQL Questions: How Do I Enable TCP Connections to MySQL?](http://nst.sourceforge.net/nst/docs/faq/ch06s04.html),

> By default, **MySQL** won't allow ANY users access to any of the databases if they connect over a `TCP` connection. In order to permit the connection, you must create a entry in the `user` table of the `mysql` database (make sure you select the `PASSWORD` function to encrypt your password). In particular, the `Host` field needs to indicate which host(s) are permitted to connect. If you specify `%` (which I would not recommend), then a user would be able to connect from any host.

Comment: Entry is already present in the table. The thing is I was able to connect to this database two weeks back, but today all of a sudden this happened.

Comment: @HakunaMatata Check again. Make sure the host field is either "172.23.251.154" or "%".

Answer (score 0):

What about firewall on port 3306?

Comment: Check if there is any bug with mysql diver.

Answer (score 0):

May be the user you are trying to access doesn't have enough privileges to access the database from the given server.

So try providing GRANTS to the user.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name TO 'user'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <password>;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

here hostname can be your host address "172.23.251.154".  Dont forget to flush privileges and then try connecting the server.

Answer (score 0):

If your MySql server is located on your host provider there is option in your control panel where you can set ip addresses from which you can connect to mysql server in your case  172.23.251.154 if this is your ip address